# Вывод шорткодов wp через js

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

Всем привет!
Столкнулся с такой проблемой, на сайте есть js который являеться фильтром и в котором есть Data (объекты с данными). Соответственно при применении фильтров какие объекты отображаются, а какие-то нет. Так вот в этих объектах есть ключи, значения которых это шорткоды плагина рейтинга, по типу [rating post_id=111].

При выводе шорткода через js он отображается просто текстом как есть "[rating post_id=111]", а нужно чтобы отображался рейтинг, наверное, есть же способы как-то выводить шорткоды через js? Возможно через function.php заранее их как-то загрузить?

Answer (score 0):

1. Если шорткод в контенте, то нужно выполнить фильтр

```
add_filter('the_content', 'do_shortcode', 11);

echo apply_filters( 'the_content', $content );
```

2. Если же шорткод за пределами контента, то можно получить вывод с помощью [do_shortcode()](https://wp-kama.ru/function/do_shortcode)

```
echo do_shortcode('[rating post_id=111]');
```

Comment: То есть в function.php нужно добавить 
`dd_filter('the_content', 'do_shortcode', 11);

echo apply_filters( 'the_content', $content );`

и тогда если через js вставлять шорткод он будет нормально отображаться?

Comment: @Nazar нужно добавить, там где формируется ответ для js

Comment: @WPPunk самое прямое. Если в выводе js есть необработанные шорткоды - значит данные под него формируются неправильно . Нужно применить правила обработки результата согласно ответу